# Advance query - Select, sum on condition and return the accumulated value

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, query-optimization, query-performance

A user predicts a team winner for a given match. Depending on which team was predicted and on whether the prediction is correct or not, different score is awarded based on the chosen team’s odds. Consider the following two SQL tables and their fields.

[image: Matches table]

and

[image]
I would like a query which sums up all users odds if the predictions were correct (meaning  `predictions.team_id` needs to match with `matches.match_winner`) for tournament ID 30. The end result should  look like this

[image]

Matthew predicted correctly match 5 and 7 (odds 3.4 + 2.4), total 5.8 points.

Neville predicted correctly match 7 and 9 (odds 2.4 + 2.0), total 4.4 points

Comment: maybe it is because your results contradics with the proposed and accepted answer. Just a guess, don't forget that we are ticking correct answers for community not for ourselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an aggredated query with a conditional `SUM` like :

```
SELECT
    p.username,
    SUM(CASE WHEN m.match_winner = m.team_a THEN m.team_a_odds ELSE m.team_b_odds END)
FROM 
    predictions p
    INNER JOIN matches m
        ON p.match_id = m.id AND p.team_id = m.match_winner
WHERE p.tournament_id = 30
GROUP BY p.username
```

Comment: `Neville predicted correctly match 7 and 9 (odds 2.4 + 2.0), total 4.4 points` this is not satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  USERNAME,
  SUM(IF(CASE WHEN MATCH_WINNER = TEAM_A, TEAM_A_ODDS, TEAM_B_ODDS))
FROM
  PREDICTIONS
INNER JOIN MATCHES
  ON MATCH_ID = MATCHES.ID AND 
    TEAM_ID = MATCH_WINNER
GROUP BY USERNAME;
```

but since `Neville predicted correctly match 7 and 9 (odds 2.4 + 2.0), total 4.4 points` does not satisfies...

```
SELECT
  USERNAME,
  SUM( TEAM_B_ODDS)
FROM
  PREDICTIONS
INNER JOIN MATCHES
  ON MATCH_ID = MATCHES.ID AND 
    TEAM_ID = MATCH_WINNER
GROUP BY USERNAME;
```

**OP is summing always TEAM_B_ODDS**

although I believe that OP evaluated `Naville` case wrong.